# How can I move apps from phone to sd card?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory, app2sd

I have an LG P769 android phone, running android 4.1.2 and my storage is only 2gb. I have a 4gb sd card inside the phone as well.  My apps are  taking up 1.32gb and I am receiving 2 warning messages: "low memory space" and "storage space is running out." My pictures and videos take up 86.81mb. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Two good starting points are our tag-wikis for the corresponding topics: [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) and [app2sd](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info). Both contain several first-aid tips and links which at least should get you started, if not even solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, apps cannot be moved to an SD card. Apps such as App2SD only move apps to 'external SD' which isn't your memory card.